# Approval – SharePoint 2013 Workflow Template missing in Office 365?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-workflow

As per [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/All-about-Approval-workflows-078c5a89-821f-44a9-9530-40bb34f9f742) article, there should be a 2013 mode Approval Workflow template in SharePoint Online, but I can't find it. I have re-activated the "Workflows" site collection feature, but I still only see the 2010 mode workflows when trying to add a workflow to a document library. What do I need to do to get the 2013 mode Approval workflow template? We have E3 plan.